# restrict website for all other IP addresses except mine

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to restrict website for all other IP addresses except mine from .htaccess
I am redirecting all others to my test.php page..

I have code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=my_ip
RewriteRule index.php$ /test.php [R=301,L]
```

But, It's still allow other IP to use website.
What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your htaccess file (obviously change the IP address to be your own):

```
Order Deny,Allow 
Allow from 1.2.3.4 
Deny from all
```

Comment: You don't need to use rewrite at all.

Comment: And, How will I redirect users to other page or website?

Comment: You could probably add an `ErrorDocument 403 /test.php`. The allow/deny commands will send back a 403 status code. That will catch the 403 and show a custom page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned mod_rewrite on? It won't do anything without the following line in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
```